# Google maps doesn't work in simplest example

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the next code:

```
<div id="gmap" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'));
</script>
```

and it's the smallest example of non-working gmap. Gmap overlay appears(without map), and when you click at map-container it throws the exception :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

I dont know, how to fix this problem, and google can't help me:| 
Please, help.

Thank you

Comment: @SalmanA no, it exists, and overlay of gmap starts rendering, but stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a default `LatLng` and some options for your map, this should work.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
```

Here's a fiddle which works:

http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/310/

When you remove the options, you get a similar problem to what you have described.

Comment: Ok, try this new answer, you are missing default options for the map.

Comment: yes! it helps) thank you very much, i don't even know, how i allowed such a mistake

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the map options when initializing your map.

The [two required options are](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) the zoom level and the position where the map is centered.

Modify your JavaScript to:

```
var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 15,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), mapOptions);
```

and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Try this one.

You need to point out atleast one cord to show map in mapoption.